# What's the least signifcant bit of a mantissa system?

Tags: arithmetic, floating-point, binary

If *Mantissa* is a 1-dot-*M* fixed-point number whose most significant bit is always  1 then, how is the least significant bit calculated?

I know the least and most significant bit of the mantissa results in the following range:

```
1.0 <_ Mantissa <_ (2.0 - 1/2^M)
```

But specifically, I don't understand where the 2 comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mantissa ranges from
$$
(1.\underbrace{0\cdots 0}_{m \text{ times}})_2 = 1
$$
to
$$
(1.\underbrace{1\cdots 1}_{m \text{ times}})_2 = 2 - (0.\underbrace{0\cdots 0}_{m-1 \text{ times}}1)_2 = 2^{-m}.
$$
For example, $(1.1)_2 = 1.5 = 2 - 1/2$ and $(1.11)_2 = 1.75 = 2 - 1/4$.

Comment: Cool! Could you tell me what does it mean the mantissa to be normalized? Tell me if I need to open a new post.

Comment: A mantissa is normalized if it is in the range $[1,2)$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number.